# Incompatibility issue between TFS 2017 Extension 4.0.2, Sonarquebe Server 6.3 and Plugin C# 6.6.0.3969

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

We are working on the migration of TFS 2015 towards TFS 2017.

We update the new SonarQube extension (4.0.2) as well as the plugin on the server for C # code (sonar-csharp-plugin-6.6.0.3969).

We are checking that the definitions of the builds with the previous tasks of sonarqube (Sonarquebe for MSBuild-Begin Analysis and SonarQube for MSBuild-End Analysis) continue to work correctly, and then we can make a modification and update plan for the new tasks proposed by the extension.

We encountered a problem when generating the build .:

> ## [error] The C # plugin installed on the SonarQube server is not compatible with the SonarQube analysis agent (i.e. the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe, or the build automation task). Either check the compatibility matrix or get the latest versions for both.
> 2018-03-19T17: 15: 08.2276942Z ## [error] Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1 "

Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the compatibility matrix `sonar-csharp-plugin-6.6.0.3969` is not compatible with SonarQube extension (4.0.2) (Scanner for MsBuild 4.0.2)

Please see the [Compatibility - SonarCloud Extension for TFS-VSTS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeExtensionforVSTS-TFS-Compatibility)  and [Compatibility - SonarQube C# plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Compatibility) for details.

In your scenario, you can try below ways to fix that:

- Install the latest plugin for C# code:
  sonar-`csharp-plugin-6.8.2.4717` ([SonarC# 6.8.2 – Feb 26, 2018 –
  SonarQube 6.7+ (Compatible with LTS)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900))
- Alternatively replace the current `Scanner for MsBuild` 4.0.x with the old
  version `3.0.0.629`. You can download `Scanner for MsBuild` from
  [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I will try to do these steps, have a nice day :)

Comment: Hi, should I change MSBuild on the TFS server or on the SonarQube server? I'm new on TFS and I do not know the Path where this is on.

Comment: @GloriaGallego You can try update the C# plugin  to 6.7+ first. based on the matrix, it should be the best way. It that works for you, then you can try the second way which downgrade to old version on the **SonarQube server**. See [Install the SonarScanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Install+the+SonarScanner+for+MSBuild) to install it.